# Why use JUnit for testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

Maybe my question is a newbie one, but I can not really understand the circumstances under which I would use [junit](/questions/tagged/junit)?

Whether I write simple applications or larger ones I test them with the `System.out` statements and it seams quite easy to me.

Why create test-classes with JUnit, unnecessary folders in the project if we still have to call the same methods, check what they return and we then have an overhead of annotating everything?

Why not write a class and test it at once with `System.out` but not create Test-classes?

PS. I have never worked on large projects I am just learning.

So what is the purpose?

Comment: Read [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.amazon.com/Art-Unit-Testing-Examples-Net/dp/1933988274)

Comment: You are aware that every time you change anything in your program, all your previous work of manually examining output is invalidated and you have to redo them from start?

Comment: Not just "testing", but also "clever testing" is very important. Here is a nice example of it: http://wp.me/prMeE-11

Answer (score 149, accepted):

That's not testing, that's "looking manually at output" (known in the biz as LMAO). More formally it's known as "looking manually for abnormal output" (LMFAO). <sup>(See note below)</sup>

Any time you change code, you must run the app and LMFAO for all code affected by those changes. Even in small projects, this is problematic and error-prone.

Now scale up to 50k, 250k, 1m LOC or more, and LMFAO any time you make a code change. Not only is it unpleasant, it's impossible: you've scaled up the combinations of inputs, outputs, flags, conditions, and it's difficult to exercise all possible branches.

Worse, LMFAO might mean visiting pages upon pages of web app, running reports, poring over millions of log lines across dozens of files and machines, reading generated and delivered emails, checking text messages, checking the path of a robot, filling a bottle of soda, aggregating data from a hundred web services, checking the audit trail of a financial transaction...  you get the idea. "Output" doesn't mean a few lines of text, "output" means aggregate system behavior.

[image]

Lastly, unit and behavior tests *define* system behavior. Tests can be run by a continuous integration server and checked for correctness. Sure, so can `System.out`s, but the CI server isn't going to know if one of them is wrong–and if it does, they're unit tests, and you might as well use a framework.

No matter how good we think we are, humans aren't good unit test frameworks or CI servers.

---

Note: LMAO *is* testing, but in a *very* limited sense. It isn't repeatable in any meaningful way across an entire project or as part of a process. It's akin to developing incrementally in a REPL, but never formalizing those incremental tests.

Comment: -1 for the first sentence, which is completely and utterly untrue.

Answer (score 51):

We write tests to verify the correctness of a program's behaviour.

Verifying the correctness of a program's behaviour by inspecting the content of output statements using your **eyes** is a *manual*, or more specifically, a *visual* process.

You could argue  that

> *visual inspection works*, I check that the code does what it's meant to
>   do, for these scenarios and once I can see it's correct we're good to
>   go.

Now first up, it's great to that you are interested in whether or not the code works correctly. That's a good thing. You're ahead of the curve! Sadly, there are problems with this as an approach.

The first problem with visual inspection is that you're a bad welding accident away from never being able to check your code's correctness again.

The second problem is that the pair of eyes used is tightly coupled with the brain of the owner of the eyes. If the author of the code also owns the eyes used in the visual inspection process, the process of verifying correctness has a dependency on the knowledge about the program internalised in the visual inspector's brain.

It is difficult for a new pair of eyes to come in and verify the correctness of the code simply because they are not partnered up with brain of the original coder. The owner of the second pair of eyes will have to *converse* with original author of the code in order to fully understand the code in question. Conversation as a means of sharing knowledge is notoriously unreliable. A point which is moot if the Original Coder is unavailable to the new pair eyes. In that instance  the new pair of eyes has to read the original code.

Reading other people's code that is not covered by unit tests is more difficult than reading code that has associated unit tests. At best reading other peoples code is tricky work, at its worst this is the most turgid task in software engineering. There's a reason that employers, when advertising job vacancies, stress that a project is a greenfield (or brand new) one. Writing code from scratch is easier than modifying existing code and thereby makes the advertised job appear more attractive to potential employees.

With unit testing we divide code up into its component parts. For each component we then set out our stall stating how the program *should behave*. Each unit test tells a story of how that part of the program should act in a specific scenario. Each unit test is like a clause in a contract that describes what should happen from the client code's point of view.

This then means that a new pair of eyes has **two** strands of **live and accurate** documentation on the code in question.

First they have the code itself, the implementation, *how the code was done*; second they have all of the knowledge that the original coder described in a set of formal statements that tell the story of how this code *is supposed to behave.*

Unit tests capture and formally describe the knowledge that the original author possessed when they implemented the class. They provide a description of how that class behaves when used by a client.

You are correct to question the usefulness of doing this because it is possible to write unit tests that are useless, do not cover all of the code in question, become stale or out of date and so on. How do we ensure that unit tests not only mimics but improves upon the process of a knowledgeable, conscientious author visually inspecting their code's output statements at runtime? Write the unit test first then write the code to make that test pass. When you are finished, let the computers run the tests, they're fast they are great at doing repetitive tasks they are ideally suited to the job.

Ensure test quality by reviewing them each time you touch off the code they test and run the tests for each build. If a test fails, fix it immediately.

We automate the process of running tests so that they are run each time we do a build of the project. We also automate the generation of code coverage reports that details what percentage of code that is covered and exercised by tests. We strive for high percentages. Some companies will prevent code changes from being checked in to source code control if they do not have sufficient unit tests written to describe any changes in behaviour to the code. Typically a second pair of eyes will review code changes in conjunction with the author of the changes. The reviewer will go through the changes ensure that the changes understandable and sufficiently covered by tests. So the review process is manual, but when the tests (unit and integration tests and possibly user acceptance tests) pass this manual review process the become part of the automatic build process. These are run each time a change is checked in. A [continuous-integration](/questions/tagged/continuous-integration) server carries out this task as part of the build process.

Tests that are automatically run, maintain the integrity of the code's behaviour and help to **prevent future changes to the code base from breaking the code**.

Finally, providing tests allows you to aggressively [re-factor code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) because you can make big code improvements safe in the knowledge that your changes do not break existing tests.

There is a caveat to [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and that is that you have to write code with an eye to making it testable. This involves coding to interfaces and using techniques such as Dependency Injection to instantiate collaborating objects. Check out the work of [Kent Beck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck) who describes TDD very well. Look up [coding to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970806/coding-to-interfaces/1970833#1970833) and study [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns)

Answer (score 13):

When you test using something like System.out, you're only testing a small subset of possible use-cases. This is not very thorough when you're dealing with systems  that could accept a near infinite amount of different inputs.

Unit tests are designed to allow you to quickly run tests on your application using a very large and diverse set of different data inputs. Additionally, the best unit tests also account for boundary cases, such as the data inputs that lie right on the edge of what is considered valid.

For a human being to test all of these different inputs could take weeks whereas it could take minutes for a machine.

Think of it like this:  You're also not "testing" something that will be static. Your application is most likely going through constant changes. Therefore, these unit tests are designed to run at different points in the compile or deployment cycle. Perhaps the biggest advantage is this:

If you break something in your code, you'll know about it *right now*, not after you deployed, not when a QA tester catches a bug, not when your clients have cancelled. You'll also have a better chance of fixing the glitch *immediately*, since it's clear that the thing that broke the part of the code in question most likely happened since your last compile. Thus, the amount of investigative work required to fix the problem is greatly reduced.

Answer (score 9):

I added some other System.out can NOT do:

- Make each test cases independent  (It's important)

  JUnit can do it: each time new test case instance will be created and `@Before` is called.
- Separate testing code from source

  JUnit can do it.
- Integration with CI

  JUnit can do it with Ant and Maven.
- Arrange and combine test cases easily

  JUnit can do `@Ignore` and test suite.
- Easy to check result

  JUnit offers many Assert methods (`assertEquals`, `assertSame`...)
- Mock and stub make you focus on the test module.

  JUnit can do: Using mock and stub make you setup correct fixture, and focus on the test module logic.

Answer (score 9):

Unit tests ensure that code works as intended. They are also very helpful to ensure that the code still works as intended in case you have to change it later to build new functionalities to fix a bug. Having a high test coverage of your code allows you to continue developing features without having to perform lots of manual tests.

Your manual approach by `System.out` is good but not the best one.This is one time testing that you perform. In real world, requirements keep on changing and most of the time you make a lot of modificaiotns to existing functions and classes. So… not every time you test the already written piece of code.

there are also some more advanced features are in JUnit like like

### Assert statements

JUnit provides methods to test for certain conditions, these methods typically start with asserts and allow you to specify the error message, the expected and the actual result

Some of these methods are

1. `fail([message])` - Lets the test fail. Might be used to check that a certain part of the code is not reached. Or to have failing test before the test code is implemented.
2. `assertTrue(true)` / `assertTrue(false)` - Will always be true / false. Can be used to predefine a test result, if the test is not yet implemented.
3. `assertTrue([message,] condition)` - Checks that the boolean `condition` is true.
4. `assertEquals([message,] expected, actual)` - Tests whether two values are equal (according to the `equals` method if implemented, otherwise using `==` reference comparison). Note: For arrays, it is the reference that is checked, and *not* the contents, use `assertArrayEquals([message,] expected, actual)` for that.
5. `assertEquals([message,] expected, actual, delta)` - Tests whether two float or double values are in a certain distance from each other, controlled by the `delta` value.
6. `assertNull([message,] object)` - Checks that the object is null

and so on. See the full Javadoc for all examples [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html).

### Suites

With Test suites, you can in a sense *combine* multiple test classes into a single unit so you can execute them all at once. A simple example, combining the test classes `MyClassTest` and `MySecondClassTest` into one Suite called `AllTests`:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ MyClassTest.class, MySecondClassTest.class })
public class AllTests { }
```

Answer (score 6):

The main advantage of JUnit is that it is automated rather than you manually having to check with your print outs. Each test you write stays with your system. This means that if you make a change that has an unexpected side effect your test will catch it and fail rather than you having to remember to manually test everything after each change.

Answer (score 4):

JUnit is a unit testing framework for the Java Programming Language. It is important in the test driven development, and is one of a family of unit testing frameworks collectively known as xUnit.

JUnit promotes the idea of "first testing then coding", which emphasis on setting up the test data for a piece of code which can be tested first and then can be implemented . This approach is like "test a little, code a little, test a little, code a little..." which increases programmer productivity and stability of program code that reduces programmer stress and the time spent on debugging.

Features
JUnit is an open source framework which is used for writing & running tests.

Provides Annotation to identify the test methods.

Provides Assertions for testing expected results.

Provides Test runners for running tests.

JUnit tests allow you to write code faster which increasing quality

JUnit is elegantly simple. It is less complex & takes less time.

JUnit tests can be run automatically and they check their own results and provide immediate feedback. There's no need to manually comb through a report of test results.

JUnit tests can be organized into test suites containing test cases and even other test suites.

Junit shows test progress in a bar that is green if test is going fine and it turns red when a test fails.

Answer (score 2):

I have slightly different perspective of why JUnit is needed.

You can actually write all test cases yourself but it's cumbersome. Here are the problems:

1. Instead of `System.out` we can add `if(value1.equals(value2))` and return 0 or -1 or error message. In this case, we need a "main" test class which runs all these methods and checks results and maintains which test cases failed and which are passed.
2. If you want to add some more tests you need to add them to this "main" test class as well. Changes to existing code. If you want to auto detect test cases from test classes, then you need to use reflection.
3. All your tests and your main class to run tests are not detected by eclipse and you need to write custom debug/run configurations to run these tests. You still don't see those pretty green/red colored outputs though.

Here is what JUnit is doing:

1. It has `assertXXX()` methods which are useful for printing helpful error messages from the conditions and communicating results to "main" class.
2. "main" class is called runner which is provided by JUnit, so we don't have to write any. And it detects the test methods automatically by reflection. If you add new tests with `@Test` annotation then they are automatically detected.
3. JUnit has eclipse integration and maven/gradle integration as well, so it is easy to run tests and you will not have to write custom run configurations.

I'm not an expert in JUnit, so that's what I understood as of now, will add more in future.

Comment: I guess in the first part you wrote what we would have done if JUnit wasn't there to make the unit testing a little better than system.out.println statements. May be JUnit is the result of such attempts by some programmers and they felt the need to write a separate testing framework to carry out this automation, thus JUnit was born, may be.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write any test case without using testing framework or else you will have to write your testing framewok to give justice to your test cases.
Here are some info about JUnit Framework apart from that you can use TestNG framework .

What is Junit?

Junit is widely used testing framework along with Java Programming Language. You can use this automation framework for both unit testing and UI testing.It helps us define the flow of execution of our code with different Annotations. Junit is built on idea of "first testing and then coding" which helps us to increase productivity of test cases and stability of the code.

Important Features of Junit Testing -

1. It is open source testing framework allowing users to write and run test cases effectively.
2. Provides various types of annotations to identify test methods.
3. Provides different Types of Assertions  to verify the results of test case execution.
4. It also gives test runners for running tests effectively.
5. It is very simple and hence saves time.
6. It provides ways to organize your test cases in form of test suits.
7. It gives test case results in simple and elegant way.
8. You can integrate jUnit with Eclipse, Android Studio, Maven & Ant, Gradle and Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

JUNIT is the method that is usually accepted by java developer.
Where they can provide similar expected input to the function and decide accordingly that written code is perfectly written or if test case fails then different approach may also need to implement.
JUNIT will make development fast and will ensure the 0 defects in the function.

Answer (score 0):

**JUNIT : OBSERVE AND ADJUST**

Here is my perspective of JUNIT.

JUNIT can be used to,
1)Observe a system behaviour when a new unit is added in that system.
2)Make adjustment in the system to welcome the "new" unit in the system.
What? Exactly.

> Real life eg.

When your relative visits your college hostel room,
1) You will pretend to be more responsible.
2) You will keep all things where they should be, like shoes in shoe rack not on chair, clothes in cupboard not on chair.
3) You will get rid of all the contraband.
4) you will start cleanUp in every device you posses.

> In programming terms

System: Your code
UNIT:  new functionality.
As JUNIT framework is used for JAVA language so JUNIT = JAVA UNIT (May be).

Suppose a you already have a well bulletproof code, but a new requirement came and you have to add the new requirement in your code. This new requirement may break your code for some input(testcase).

Easy way to adapt this change is using unit testing (JUNIT).
For that you should write multiple testcases for your code when you are building your codebase. And whenever a new requirement comes you just run all the test cases to see if any test case fails.
If No then you are a BadA** artist and you are ready to deploy the new code.
If any of the testcases fail then you change your code and again run testcases until you get the green status.