# More readbale way to test JSON parsing

Tags: ruby, json

I'm writing a program in Ruby that is parsing a fairly large JSON file. I'd like to be able to run a piece of Ruby code (in a testing environment) that parses this file, and see the information that has been extracted in a readable "pretty print" kind of way, for the sole purpose of testing.

So far I've just been testing things using `irb` in the terminal, but the output has no formatting whatsoever, so it's very difficult to figure out if things are working correctly. Is there a tool that makes JSON parsing a bit less painful?

Comment: Can't you use the json gem?

Comment: Your point is not clear. Do you want to parse JSON, or do you want to pretty print a complicated object (which has nothing to do with JSON)?

Comment: @sawa I'm writing a script that will pull info from the JSON file. I just want to know if there's some sort of testing environment I can use to run Ruby parsing code on the JSON file and then see the result of that, for the sole purpose of me seeing if it's working correctly.

Comment: What about using `jq` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl Actually, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!

Comment: please put the code you are trying to test, so that we can provide better support.

Comment: `jq` is an awesome tool; I use it all the time. These days I combine it with `http` as an easier-to-remember `curl`. But what you're doing isn't really "testing", per se, rather Looking Manually At Output (LMAO). If you want to *test*, then actually test (Java version of LMAO http://stackoverflow.com/a/10859000/438992), otherwise it's just exploration. Exploration is *good*, but transitory.

Comment: @DaveNewton Right, I have trouble sometimes articulating exactly what I'm trying to do, so apologies for misleading anyone. Thanks for info though. This will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

[awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) is a very convenient gem for this purpose. And about the REPL, I suggest to use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) instead of `irb`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using [json from the stdlib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html)?

Anyhow, you can test your code with [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) or [rspec](http://rspec.info/). I would not test for readability of your output, but rather test that given an input `X`, you get expected output `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and then paste a JSON object string into a code cleaner like http://www.dirtymarkup.com/ which will re-format the code into a more readable format.