# Game of Life Gridworld NullPointer Run-Time Error

Tags: java

Trying to make Conway's Game of Life using Gridworld.
Everything Compiles but I keep getting the error when i try to take a "step"

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Cell.processSurrondings(Cell.java:27)
at Cell.act(Cell.java:44)
at info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld.step(ActorWorld.java:68)
at info.gridworld.gui.GUIController.step(GUIController.java:134)
at info.gridworld.gui.GUIController$4.actionPerformed(GUIController.java:247)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here are the files
lifeWorld (variant of actorWorld)

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
import info.gridworld.grid.UnboundedGrid;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class lifeWorld extends ActorWorld {

    private static final String FIRST_LINE = "Welcome to Ern's Game of Life. (A rip off of Conway's Game of Life)\n" +
            "Click a live cell to kill it, a dead cell to resurect it, or run to run the cycles!";

    public lifeWorld() {
        setGrid(new UnboundedGrid<Actor>());
        System.setProperty("info.gridworld.gui.selection", "hide");
        System.setProperty("info.gridworld.gui.tooltips", "hide");
        System.setProperty("info.gridworld.gui.frametitle", "Ern's Game of Life");
    }


    private String setMessage() {
        return FIRST_LINE;
    }

    public boolean locationClicked(Location loc) {
        if (getGrid().get(loc) == null)
            new Cell().putSelfInGrid(getGrid(), loc);
        else
            getGrid().get(loc).removeSelfFromGrid();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Cell (variant of Critter)

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Cell extends Actor {

    private boolean planning;   
    private boolean dies;
    private ArrayList<Location> cellsToAdd;

    public Cell() {
        setColor(Color.BLACK);
        planning = true;
        dies = false;
    }

    private void processSurrondings(){
        ArrayList<Location> adjCells = getGrid().getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(getLocation());
        ArrayList<Location> cellsAdd = new ArrayList<Location>();
        if(adjCells.size() > 0)
            for(Location a: adjCells)
                if(getGrid().getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(a).size() == 3)
                    cellsToAdd.add(a); //The error happens here apparently
        ArrayList<Location> isDead = getGrid().getOccupiedAdjacentLocations(getLocation());
        dies = (!(isDead.size() == 2 || isDead.size() == 3));
    }

    private void executeStep() {
        for(Location a: cellsToAdd){
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.putSelfInGrid(getGrid(),a);

        }
        if(dies)
            removeSelfFromGrid();
    }   

    public void act() {
        if (planning) {
            processSurrondings();
            planning = !(planning);
        }
        else
            this.executeStep();
    }   
}
```

GameOfLifeRunner (the runner/driver file)

```
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
import info.gridworld.grid.UnboundedGrid;
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;

public class GameOfLifeRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lifeWorld world = new lifeWorld();
        world.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is where a debugger would be really handy. If you used one, you could examine the exact state of your program right at the moment when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize the `List` `cellsToAdd` in the class `Cell`:

```
private ArrayList<Location> cellsToAdd;
```

causing an `NPE` to be thrown on this line:

```
cellsToAdd.add(a);
```

You could do this in the constructor of `Cell`:

```
public Cell() {
   cellsToAdd = new ArrayList<Location>();
   ...
```

*Aside:* The preferred approach in Java is to code to an interface. This allows implementations which as `List` to be easily swapped for other implementations.

```
private List<Location> cellsToAdd;
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970806/coding-to-interfaces)