# In terms of scalability would be wiser to make an object from the concrete class or the interface?

Tags: java, oop, scalability

For example instead of:

```
LinkedStack<Integer> list = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
```

Should be this:

```
StackInterface<Integer> list = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970806/coding-to-interfaces

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way is called **code to interfaces**.

[Reference link](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html)

second way is prefarable like. use interface as refference for subclass object.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

```
LinkedStack<Integer> list = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
```

is better **only** if you need specific methods on LinkedStack that are not declared in `StackInterface`.

```
StackInterface<Integer> list = new LinkedStack<Integer>();
```

is better if you do not, because then you can 'plug in' any implementer of the interface for different reasons (efficiency reasons for example).

Comment: I still don't find a good reason to use first option. If I have to use it by some means, I would prefer to encapsulate that portion of the code in a method with a comment warning that this method will try to use a specific implementation of the interface for a very specific job e.g. `TreeMap` or `TreeSet`.