# Why the coding should be "to the interface" especially for primitive datatypes?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface

I have a doubt on the design methodology that why we implement the code to the interface. This is very much observed in primitive data types. Like I am not getting the difference between these two  :

```
Map<Integer, String> mymap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

And

```
HashMap<Integer, String> mymap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Is there any difference between these two? I mean each and every place where we are going to use `mymap` will remain same in both the cases.

I am sorry if the question seems to be of no use but I really not getting that how this is going to make any difference later on where `mymap` will be used. Please help?

Thanks..

Note - I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48605/1130032) question on SO but it is not giving what I want.

Comment: What is it specifically about the other question you link to that isn't giving you what you want?

Comment: the question u have linked has got very good answers

Comment: But I didn't get my answer as there is nothing specified about primitive types interface coding style as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: `Map` is not a primitive type. `int` is, `boolean` is, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because mymap can be instantiated somewhere else with a different implementation of `Map`, you should not rely on it being an instance of  `HashMap` in the code using it.

Comment: I got you but can you please elaborate any case where I should not rely on it being an instance of `HashMap` ??

Comment: For example if it is created as a TreeMap.

Comment: Nonsense; the example explicitly initializes it as `new HashMap`. The only thing that does is hiding `HashMap`-specific functionality. Unless that type comes from an external source and it returned as the interface type, there is _never_ a reason to do this.

Answer (score 7):

The second option limits you to always use HashMap, even if some day TreeMap could be more useful.

In the first one you can change the particular implementation easier  - you only have to change one line of code. It's especially visible if you return your map from methods - the method return type doesn't have to change.

Coding to an interface also helps mocking the object during tests, but I assume that's not the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..!! +1 for `return type not have to change`.

Comment: The second option also _removes all specific functionality of `HashMap`_. If you _want_ the extra functions available from the `HashMap` type, you shouldn't needlessly restrict the type. The old "you can swap it out later" argument is stupid; that just means the initial evaluation of the required functionality for the map was done poorly. Restricting the return type for no other reason than that also just needlessly hides functionality that _should_ be available on the calling level.

Comment: @Nyerguds No one is arguing against exposing the functionality when needed. The point here is that one should try expose *as little as necessary* to give themselves flexibility later. If you need `HashMap` then go ahead and use `HashMap`, but if all you need is a `Map` then use that, even if the implementing type happens to be a `HashMap`.

Comment: @soulcheck Again, that only applies to return types. I see no conceivable reason to put that in your initial declaration. And "flexibility later" isn't a reason; it's the same nonsensical "you can swap it out later" argument. You want to swap it out later? Then you did it wrong first, and deserve the extra work.

Comment: What kind of argument is: " you did it wrong first, and deserve the extra work"? If you can avoid that extra work at pretty much no cost then why wouldn't you?

Comment: @soulcheck: What kind of argument is "I'll just restrict myself now, on the slim chance it turns out I did it all wrong and I need to redo it later"? Which case do you think is more likely? Actually finding the extra functionality of the implementing class useful, or having to refactor the whole project?

Comment: Mind you, on classes that really are just straightforward implementations of interfaces, this is indeed trivial. But more often than not, there _is_ useful extra functionality on the implementing classes.

Comment: @Nyerguds you can contrast your anecdotical evidence with mine all day - changing implementation class happens all the time while actually using any particular characteristics of, for example, `HashMaps` or `TreeMaps` after instantiation happens seldom in my case. OP observed coding vs interface in the wild, he asked a question about what he saw and got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map mymap` allows you to change the implementation later. For example, if at some point you need `mymap` to be ordered, you just change the initialization to `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using this inside your type (meaning: private) and instantiate it yourself, it doesn't make a real difference.

It starts getting interesting if the public interface of your type exposes a Map vs. a HashMap.

Comment: If, later on, in your private method, you decide a TreeMap would be a better collection, coding to the interface still protects you even in a private method.

Comment: IMHO this advantage is more theoretical than practical: Mostly, you will only have to change the field / variable declaration specifying the data type. According to my experience, interfaces often lack methods which the concrete type offers causing reimplementations of existing functionality or casts. Nevertheless, it's a good practice to think about the "right" data type for fields in variables also for private members.

Comment: @winSharp Map is pretty much complete though. Apart from `putIfAbsent` you can even use say a `ConcurrentHashMap` without problems.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific instance you propose, it may not make a difference, but it's good practice to get yourself used to always use the interface in your declarations because there are legitimate instances where you will **need** that flexibility.

Comment: It's good practice to deliberately never make use of the specific functions available on `HashMap` or `ArrayList` objects? That's what you're claiming?

Answer (score 0):

The former allows you to change to:

```
Map<Integer, String> mymap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
```

for example, without breaking all the rest of your code.

A much more minor advantage is that your IDE can show you the methods for the interface, rather than the (potentially much larger number of) methods for the implementation.