# ArrayList declaration in java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

Is this formula is legal in java to declare **ArrayList**

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: No. It would have been faster to try it than writing a question.

Comment: `List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 provides several alternatives, such as:

```
List<Integer> list1 = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).boxed().collect(toList());
List<Integer> list1 = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).boxed().collect(toList());
```

With Java 7 you need to use:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); //can't add or remove
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cant do use it like that
Have a read of both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321177/arraylist-declaration-java). These two pages would clear all your doubts regarding declaring arrayLists.
Or if you just want the solution, `List<Integer> list1=  new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));`

Answer (score 0):

No, But there are other ways to do that,

```
List<Integer> list1= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
```

or you an use anonymous inner class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with that array initialization notation like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));
```