# How to declare an ArrayList with values?

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization, declare

[ArrayList or List declaration in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321177/arraylist-declaration-java) has questioned and answered how to declare an empty `ArrayList` but how do I declare an ArrayList with values?

I've tried the following but it returns a syntax error:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
        x = ['xyz', 'abc'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 478, accepted):

In Java 9+ you can do:

```
var x = List.of("xyz", "abc");
// 'var' works only for local variables
```

---

Java 8 using [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
Stream.of("xyz", "abc").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

And of course, you can create a new object using the constructor that accepts a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html):

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc"));
```

---

Tip: The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) contains very useful information that usually contains the answer you're looking for. For example, here are the constructors of the `ArrayList` class:

- [`ArrayList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--)

  > Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
- [`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) (*)

  > Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.
- [`ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-)

  > Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Comment: Use List on the LHS rather than ArrayList, if you don't absolutly need an ArrayList there. And use the diamond operator on the RHS to avoid warnings.

Comment: Why you wrap by new ArrayList<>()? `List<String> x = Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc")` is ok

Comment: No harm in repeating parts of the doc - StackOverflow is probably more visited anyway.

Comment: `List.of()`is Java 9, not 10+: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: @mystdeim Because Arrays.asList returns an unmodifiable list, meaning trying to add/remove an element it will throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Minor side note: the first example using List.of() returns an immutable list, and not specifically an ArrayList as the question requested.

Answer (score 41):

Use:

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc"));
```

If you don't want to add new elements to the list later, you can also use ([Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) returns a fixed-size list):

```
List<String> x = Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc");
```

Note: you can also use a static import if you like, then it looks like this:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
```

...

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<>(asList("xyz", "abc"));
```

or

```
List<String> x = asList("xyz", "abc");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixed size. It is faster on `contains` method of `Set<List<T>> = Arrays.asList("a","b");`

Answer (score 31):

You can do like this :

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1", "12"));
```

Answer (score 11):

The [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) contains convenience methods for creating lists and other collections which makes this much prettier than using the standard library classes.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> list = newArrayList("a", "b", "c");
```

(This assumes `import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;`)

Answer (score 10):

Try this!

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc"));
```

It's a good practice to declare the `ArrayList` with interface `List` if you don't have to invoke the specific methods.

Answer (score 6):

Use this one:

```
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("abc", "mno"));
```