# Initialise ArrayList of unknown size in contractor - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, initialization

I am looking to populate an array in the constructor with string values whenever a new instance is created. I am getting the following error in my code when I try to create an instance.

```
Array initialiser not allowed here.
```

Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    .....
    Activities coldDrink = new Activities("string", 1, 1, {"string", "stringOne", "stringTwo"});
    ....
}
```

Activities Class

```
public class Activities {
  private String activityName;
  private int numberEssentialSensors;
  private int numberOptionalSensors;
  private ArrayList sensorList = null;


  Activities(String actName, int essSensors, int optSensors, ArrayList arrayValues) {
    this.activityName = actName;
    this.numberEssentialSensors = essSensors;
    this.numberOptionalSensors = optSensors;
    this.sensorList = arrayValues;

  }
```

Comment: Are you doing that in the constructor? Please note that usage of raw-type collections is not encouraged.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696784/how-to-declare-an-arraylist-with-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{"string", "stringOne", "stringTwo"}` is an array initialization expression, not an `ArrayList`. You can use `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("string", "stringOne", "stringTwo"))` instead.

It would be better to use `ArrayList<String>` instead of the raw type though.

```
Activities coldDrink = new Activities("string", 1, 1, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("string", "stringOne", "stringTwo"));
```