# What is the difference between using superclass to initialise the subclass object and vice versa?

Tags: java, oop

Can you please tell me difference between these three in respect to their usage :-

```
Superclass p1 = new Superclass();
Superclass p2 = new Subclass();
Subclass p3 = new Subclass();
```

Comment: @PatrickM I see no connection between that question and this one.

Comment: @PatrickM that's a completely different question.

Comment: My bad, misread the inheritance between the examples. The 2nd answer looked like a thorough explanation of different inherited  constructors. Close vote retracted. (But surely this has been answered on SO already...)

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321177/arraylist-or-list-declaration-in-java

Answer (score 6):

The first one and the 3rd one make respective objects of the type declared - usage is perfect, and you get all the expected methods.

The second one gives you the functionality of only the Superclass even though you actually have a Subclass object, because you declared it as a Superclass.

eg:

`Superclass p1 = new Superclass();` Your p1 object has access to Superclass methods.

`Superclass p2 = new Subclass();` Your p2 object only has access to Superclass methods. The program doesn't know p2 has Subclass specific methods because you declared it as a Superclass.

`Subclass p3 = new Subclass();` Your p3 object has access to all Subclass and Superclass methods.

Note for using p2 method of declaration: Given the following classes A and B

```
public class A {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("yyy");
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public B() {
        super();
    }

    public void print() { // this overrides the print() method in A
        System.out.println("xxx");
    }

    public void printb() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
}
```

This happens in code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A x =  new B();

    x.print(); // prints xxx because you actually have a B object even though you have an A reference
    x.printB(); // doesn't compile. You can't call B specific methods through an A reference.
}
```

Comment: So accordingly, 1st and 2nd one are same?

Comment: @Aify you're saying that the p2 object only has access to Superclass methods. Cannot the subclass methods get invoked polymorphically though?

Comment: As suggested by @Aify what is the use of subclass object in second if it cannot access the subclass methods and variables?

Comment: To be frank, I would almost always declare my objects using the first/third methods. Actually, I've never used the second method before.

@Atomheartfather I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @pranavj95 no, they are different. p2 will hold a reference to an instance of the subclass.

Comment: As far as I know, I think that p2 can access subclasses method too, though I am not sure. The only difference which I know is that p2 will by default access Superclass method even if they are being overloaded in Subclass. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Aify Subclss can override some of the methods defined in Superclass. If you invoke one of those on p2, the method from the subclass gets executed.

Comment: Your p2 (Subclass) object can't access Subclass methods if you're using a Superclass reference. And Atom, yes - I'll edit my answer to differentiate between pure superclass/sublcass methods and add a point on overriding methods.

Comment: @pranavj95 Java is polymorphic, hence the overridden method (the one from the Subclass will be executed).

Answer (score 1):

The first and the last are just usual variable declaration and class instantiation.

The second

`Superclass p2 = new Subclass();`

declares a variable `p2` of type `Superclass` that can either store a `Superclass` instance or any instance of a subclass of `Superclass`. From `p2` you can only access members that are already provided in `Superclass`, although their behavior can be different due to overriding in `Subclass`.

Also, you can check what actual type is stored in `p2` by using `instanceof`. If you know the actual type, you could cast `p2` to another variable of the sub-class type.

```
if (p2 instanceof Subclass)
    Subclass p4 = (Subclass)p2;
```

Comment: p2 could access the method provided in the subclass and not in it's super class..Please correct me if I'm wrong..