# How to use a hashmap and array list with a key mapping to multiple values?

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to make a HashMap such that the keys are months of the year and the values are names of peoples who's birthday it is in that month. I am quite stuck and don't know exactly what's wrong. Help is much appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class BirthdayStore {

HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

public BirthdayStore() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
}

public boolean containsKey(String key) {
    if(map.containsKey(key)) {
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}

public void put(String key, String word) {
    if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist.add(word);
    }
    else{
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = (ArrayList<String>) map.get(key);
        arraylist.add(word);

    }
    }
public List<String> get(String key) {
    return map.get(key);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BirthdayStore k = new WordStore();
    k.put("september","jack" );
    k.put("september","josh" );
    k.put("january","james");

    System.out.println(k.get("september"));
}
}
```

Currently, my output is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call your `put()` method, you create the arraylist and all, but you don't put that arraylist into your map.

```
public void put(String key, String word) {
    if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist.add(word); // <-- here you made a new arraylist and added your word to it, but what are you doing with this array list? 
                             // You're not putting it into the HashMap for this key
        map.put(key, arraylist); // <-- you have to remember to actually put the arraylist into the map! 
    }
    else{
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = (ArrayList<String>) map.get(key);
        arraylist.add(word);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh man I feel so dumb. Well at least I'm learning. Thank you so much for your response, very clear and the comments helped a lot. Much love.

Comment: No problem! If you wouldn't mind, could you please mark the solution as accepted to help provide some closure to the question? Thanks and good luck with learning Java!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Raizuri's answer, just let you know that there is a quite useful method for HashMaps, `getOrDefault`, which retrieves the value for a key and lets you define a default value which is returned in case your key is absent in the map. This way you don't have to use the conditional case:

```
public void put(String key, String word) {
    List<String> monthBirthdays = map.getOrDefault(key, new ArrayList<>());
    monthBirthdays.add(word);
    map.put(key, monthBirthdays);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use List<String> instead of ArrayList on the second line?

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing, I think it's a bit subjective. `List` is an interface that `ArrayList` implements, so the benefits of using a more generic declaration type is that you could change your implementation to use `LinkedList` (which also implements `List`) and you wouldn't have to change the declaration. You also depend less on specific `ArrayList` implementation details, which is generally good. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321177/arraylist-or-list-declaration-in-java).